# Adding items to a list each time a button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to create a program that adds a number to a list every time you press a button but I am a bit stuck and I don't know why I keep getting an error every time I run the code. Some help would really be appreciated as I don't know what to do

Comment: You should add any error message you receive during compile and runtime to your question.

Comment: Why was the code removed from this question? It makes even less sense without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that you try this: `String.valueOf(result))`, while `result` is a `JButton`. But there is no point in trying to convert the button to a string.

What I think you are trying to achieve here is, that you retrieve the content from the input textfield, convert it to a number and add it to your list. So it should probably look something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // you want to store integers right?
result.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            int temp = Integer.parseInt(input.getText()); // get the input
            list.add(temp); // add it to the list
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // error handling
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it keeps saying "cannot infer type arguments for java.util.ArrayList<>" every time I run the code

Comment: As already stated by @OHGODSPIDERS in the other answer, you imported the incorrect list. To go around that, simply use `java.util.ArrayList` like shown in the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

```
error message:java: type java.awt.List does not take parameters
```

The Problem is that there is more than one class/interface with the name `List` in the Java standard libraries.

Since you have imported all classes of `java.awt` with a wildcard in

```
import java.awt.*;
```

The compiler thinks that in your line

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You are refering to the class `java.awt.List` and not `java.util.List`.

I would personally recommend not to use any wildcards for importing. Any good IDE will be able to help you handle your imports so that you should be able to import the correct List Interface

```
 import java.util.List;
```

Alternativly you can also use the full package name when using the List interface in your class:

```
java.util.List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```